# SSIS project build on local is OK but failing on build server - Name cannot begin with the ' ' character

Tags: ssis, msbuild, devops

I have SSIS project that was origianlly developed on VS 2016 for SQL 2014.
After update to SQL 2019 and VS 2019 one of our build pipelines in DevOps is not working as expected.

After updating project to new version everything works as should in Visual Studio. Integrations are working, building as well and builded package can be deployed on SSIS Server.

But our DevOps build on our dedicated build server is not working any more. What I know we have all required componets installed on build server. Any idea what can be issue. Local build is ok, remote failing everytme (error below). From error it's not clear what file is wrong but what I checked all looks normal and local build is working.

Any idea appreciated.

System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 364.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32& colonPos)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.ParsePartialContent(XmlNode parentNode, String innerxmltext, XmlNodeType nt)
at System.Xml.XmlElement.set_InnerXml(String value)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.RuntimeObjectModel.Default.PackageParameter.Save(XmlNode parentNode)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.RuntimeObjectModel.Default.PackageParameters.Save(XmlNode parentNode)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.RuntimeObjectModel.Default.Package.Save()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.Save()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.SavePackage(Package package, String streamName)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Save(Object events, Boolean preserveGuid)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)

Checked installed components.
Logs.